# Should I declare Numbers as Strings?

Tags: javascript, json, spring, angular

I have a very simple object

```
export class Environment {
   name:string;
   activityDays:number = 1; //default value
}
```

but when I post it.

```
return this._http.post<any>(RequestProperties.baseUrl + "/environment/create", JSON.stringify(environment), this.options);
```

I get an error because the number doesn't have a `""`

Payload `{"activityDays":1,"name":"test"}`

My Spring controller throw Error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token

So Should I put all my numbers as string??

Spring controller

```
@PostMapping("/environment/create")
public boolean createEnvironment(@RequestBody Environment environment) {
    System.out.println("xDD");

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Either change your backend to accept a numbuer if that's what you want or change `JSON.stringify(environment)` to `JSON.stringify({...environment, activityDays: `${environment.activityDays}`})`

Comment: *"So Should I put all my numbers as string?"* No, you should update your deserialization (Spring) code/declaration to understand that `activityDays` is a number (specifically, a `double` although you can probably map it to an `int` if it's always a whole number).

Comment: the whole point of using Spring is that it does the magic alone. I just need to pass the json

Comment: In the backend activityDays is a int.